# Compute a column based on the comparison of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compute a column based on the comparison of two queries. Take for instance these two queries that use the same table. The only difference is the dates.

```
-Query for Monday
|Balance: 1,000

-Query for Tuesday
|Balance: 900
```

After comparison the column I am attempting to create should be this ( based off those two queries):

```
-Column "payment" 
|Payment: 100
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the two queries:

```
SELECT     monday_payment - tuesday_payment AS balance
FROM       (SELECT payment AS monday_payment
            FROM   some_table
            WHERE  some_date = /* monday */) m -- Assume this returns one line
CROSS JOIN (SELECT payment AS tuesday_payment
            FROM   some_table
            WHERE  some_date = /* monday */) t -- Assume this returns one line
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many ways to skin the proverbial SQL cat, here is another option:

> select 
>   sum(case
>       when date = monday then balance
>   end) - sum(case
>       when date = tuesday then balance
>   end)
>   from table
>   where date in (monday, tuesday)